What is best practise for long running sudo commands?
I have build a function, which calls sudo commands from python, because I don't want to run every command as sudo (I am pulling in the process data from a repo, which I control, but this could be an angle of attack I wanted to mitigate):
streamer = SysStreamer

def _logable_sudo(cmds: List[str], password: str) -> List[str]:
       sudo_cmds = ["sudo", "-S"]
       sudo_cmds.extend(cmds)

       streamer.stream_command(
           sudo_cmds,
           stdout_handler=self.streamer.stdout_handler,
           stdin=PIPE,
           password=password,
       )

       return streamer.stdout_lines

Where SysStreamer is the following class:
class SysStreamer:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.flush_stdout_cache()
        self.logger = load_logger(__name__)

    def flush_stdout_cache(self):
        self.stdout_lines = []

    def stream_command(
        self,
        args,
        *,
        stdout_handler=logging.info,
        check=True,
        text=True,
        stdin=None,
        stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=STDOUT,
        password=None,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        """Mimic subprocess.run, while processing the command output in real time."""
        with Popen(args, text=text, stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, **kwargs) as process:
            if password:
                process.stdin.write(f"{password}\n")
                process.stdin.flush()
            for line in process.stdout:
                stdout_handler(line[:-1])
        retcode = process.poll()
        if check and retcode:
            raise CalledProcessError(retcode, f"{process.args}:Check Logs!")
        return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode)

    def stdout_handler(self, line):
        self.logger.info(line)
        self.stdout_lines.append(line)

The SysStreamer is just a workaround to have access to the return values of the process and also save them for other use cases.
The Issue I have with this approach, that I need to gather the Password myself and having it in plaintext visible while debugging.
So my first intention was to use the systems sudo call instead of requesting the password earlier before the sudo call and I think it would be the best approach. The only thing what is worrying me: What if I need to call a second sudo call later, and the sudo-timer has reseted?
I had this issue with this specific workflow in the past and I needed to run the complete workflow again to verify that the system is in the actual needed state.
So my final question: How should I handle sudo and help the process not to reset the sudo-timer, while my script is still running?

Consider starting your main process under sudo but dropping those privileges for the less-trusted operations. sudo gives you environment variables naming the original account, so you can pass that account name to setpriv, chpst, or similar tools to switch back to it. That also gets you out of the business of handling passwords, which you don't want to be in.

(One of the faults you get with passwords, btw -- depending on /etc/sudoers there may not be any password prompt at all, or sudo -S can be categorically disabled and operation without a TTY outright disallowed, so having code that unconditionally writes to the stdin of sudo -S ... is problematic)
